# opencart rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, opencart

Website use the opencart cms, SEO url enabled, so the .htaccess looks :

```
 RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

all works perfect, but i wanted to add the 301 redirect from non www to www, so i added:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works, but when i try to redirect link with category or product it adds "index.php?*route*="

Example:

"www.example.com/cats", if i try "example.com/cats" without "www" the link will look www.example.com/index.php?*route*=cats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add all of your redirects **before** any routing rules (e.g. the rules you have that route things to `index.php`. So your htaccess file needs to look something like this:

```
# redirect rules first
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# then routing rules
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you mate.. I can't believe i wasted 2 hours to fix the code and all i needed was to put redirects before the routing rules.. lol

Comment: @RaShe Yeah, the key concept here is that although you have the `L` flag which stops rewriting in the current iteration, mod_rewrite will continue to loop through all the rules until the URI stops changing. So when you have the routing first, the routing gets applied and the URI changes, but then the second time around, the redirect gets applied **with the already rewritten URI**.